# How to stop Jquery Ajax “pages unresponsive you can wait for it to become responsive or exit the page” popup error in chrome browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have popup issue with Google Chrome browser.
I am using .Net MVC ajax method, The ajax call to server(controller) side and it take long time execution (50 sec to 2 mins and above).
This time Chrome browser shows "pages unresponsive, you can wait for it to become responsive or exit the page" error popup message.
I'm searching many website.Still i didn't get any solution regarding this.

some website says:
**async: false**   change to  **async: true**

**async: true** change means its working fine. But **async: true** means first ajax call execute (success function) response before going to next statement.
Next next statement execute after finally comes first ajax success function response.
so I need first ajax call execute and when (success function) response return  after goto next statement and
how to stop  “pages unresponsive you can wait for it to become responsive or exit the page” popup window error in chrome browser.
[image]
ajax Code:

```
$.ajax({
        url: "../Report/MonthlyOrder",
        type: "POST",
        async: false,
        //async: true,
        dataType="json",
        data:{FromDate:fromDate,ToDate:toDate},
        success: function (response) {
             //.......
        }
    });

    //Next Staement
    //function 1
    //function 2
```

Please help me ...!
Thanks in Advance....

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you'll just have to refactor your code to be able to use `async: true`, i.e. put that "next statement" and so on inside `success`, or maybe use the promise-like interface:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "../Report/MonthlyOrder",
  type: "POST",
  async: true,
  dataType: "json",
  data: { FromDate: fromDate, ToDate: toDate },
}).done((response) => {
  // next statement...
});
```

If you're in an environment where you can use async/await and real promises, this could be made easier still.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable response.
But i need to use next statement for outside of ajax.
Because, i am using forloop inside single ajax function , and ajax url passing dynamically (loop based).
I am trying your code written below:

Comment: function Reportfun() {
    var objReoprt = [];
    var arrayReoprt = []
    objReoprt.url = "../Report/MonthlyOrderExecute1";
    arrayReoprt.push(objReoprt);
    objReoprt = [];
    objReoprt.url = "../Report/MonthlyOrderExecute2";
    arrayReoprt.push(objReoprt);
    objReoprt = [];
    objReoprt.url = "../Report/MonthlyOrderExecute3";
    arrayReoprt.push(objReoprt);
     for (var i = 0; i < arrayReoprt.length; i++) {
        var result = ExecuteAjaxFunction(arrayReoprt[i].url);
        if (result == 0) break;
    }
}

Comment: function ExecuteAjaxFunction(url) {
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: "POST",
        async: true,
        dataType: "json",
    }).done(function (response) {
        //.done((response) => {
        alert(response + " - " + url);
        return response;
    });
}

Comment: output:
First return this url=>MonthlyOrderExecute3
Secound return this url=>MonthlyOrderExecute2
Third return this url=>MonthlyOrderExecute1
Please Help.....

Comment: Please edit that code into your original question, not into a comment here.